# is there a way to access the -rotate option in ImageMagick -annotate in wand?

Tags: python, text, rotation, imagemagick, wand

In Imagemagick, there is a **-rotate** option which can be provided with -annotate to rotate text relative to the image.  I do not see how to do this in wand.  I am thinking of making a private version of wand with this option added, but the coding is a bit advanced for me.  Is there a way to support it?

The hack would be use python to create "convert" command lines which are sent to a shell for execution, but obviously I'd rather use a python binding.

I used to do this sort of thing with PerlMagick.

I tried setting draw.rotate or draw.rotation variables, but inspection of the source code makes it clear these are not supported.

Comment: Documentation for annotate at https://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.6.7/wand/image.html  shows: "angle (numbers.Real) – Degree rotation to draw text at."  Did you read the documentation?